# Fancybox 3 metod to scroll down fancy popup

Tags: javascript, fancybox, fancybox-3

I need some method to scroll Fancybox popup down or scroll to element which is in the popup (when the poopup opened obviosly)

I red the documenmtation buut did not find the way.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in method and you can simply use plain JavaScript (or jQuery) to scroll your element wherever you want. Maybe you can simply trigger focus on your element and the browser will do the rest.

Comment: Could u help me plz to find out which of fancybox divs sould i interact wuth to scroll?

Comment: You use fancybox to display your element, so.... sorry, but your question does not make any sense. You do not know how to find your div element or what?